# Make a div stick to the left when scrolling

Tags: javascript, css

So I am trying to create a left-sided nav bar, but after scrolling I can't get it to correctly stay to the left.

I have tried using:

```
position: fixed;
```

and

```
position: absolute;
```

However it cuts the width of the DIV down completely.

To get a view of what I'm working with go to: `http://198.50.242.77/YouBB/`

I'd prefer to use strictly CSS only but if I must use JS I'll use it.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post all relevant CSS and HTML. It's hard I diagnose the problem with no code. If you have tried position fixed and that causes width issues, in my experience it's due to parent elements with % widths. I suggest reading up on papist ion fixed as it has some what unique behaviour.

Comment: You should use `position` not `display` for this... That `CSS` is not valid!

Comment: Seems fine to me, if you are talking about the white div on the left. It is responsive and get cut only on low resolutions, for which you can use CSS min-width property. Also, like the others said, it is position: fixed;

Comment: Sorry yes I meant position: fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`position: fixed` is what you want. This causes the element to be removed from the flow entirely and stay in the same position even after scrolling the page.

`position: absolute` is similar, but it only removes an element from the flow. Scrolling a containing div (or in this case, the whole page) will still cause it to move.

I opened up your web page in Chrome, and changed the styles for `#navigation` to:

```
background: white;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
position: fixed;
width: 18.72%;
```

This does what you want. You will just need to position the rest of the content to the right.

Comment: I.e. `fixed` will position the element relative to the initial containing block while `absolute` will position the element relative to it's containing block which is established by the nearest ancestor with a `position` of `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`.

Comment: Just a simple position:fixed; ruins the alignment of everything.

Comment: @DavidChalifoux By removing the left panel from document normal flow you have to push the right column to the right by `margin-left: 18.72%;`

Comment: @DavidChalifoux yes. web design often requires effort. to fix something, you often have to break something else, then fix *that*. :)

Comment: Yes I know how to move an object back over, but I'm unsure about what I should do about the left-side nav bar losing it's width.

Comment: @DavidChalifoux set a width for it in css.

Comment: @DavidChalifoux i opened up your web page in chrome, added `position: fixed` and `width: 18.72%` to `#navigation`'s styles. this works fine.

Comment: @sgroves then could it be due to the parent div's width being different?

Comment: @DavidChalifoux oh. you didn't have `width` set on `#navigation`, you had it set on `.col.span_1_of_5`. that won't work because `#navigation` has `position: fixed`. the `width` property needs to be set directly on the `fixed` element. `fixed` elements do NOT inherit width. they're totally removed from the flow.

Comment: @sgroves I fixed it. I just set position:fixed on the .col.span1_5_of_5 and some over things and it's perfectly responsive again.